# What is the difference between including ActiveModel vs. ActiveModel::Model, in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I thought including `ActiveModel` would allow you to treat an object in the same way as an `ActiveRecord`, without persisting it to the database. I know that `ActiveModel::Model` allows you to do validations and such, but wouldn't just including `ActiveModel` also do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not the same. Including `ActiveModel` doesn't provide you with the methods for validations. One of the methods `ActiveModel::Model` gives you is `persisted?`, which returns `false` by default. You can verify this with a test in the Rails console:

```
class Test; include ActiveModel; end; Test.new.persisted?
# NoMethodError: undefined method `persisted?' for #<Test:0x007f84ddd6d620>

class Test; include ActiveModel::Model; end; Test.new.persisted?
# false
```

The `ActiveModel` module only defines some references to autoload submodules ([check the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model.rb)). It doesn't actually mix any methods into your class.

`ActiveModel::Model` on the other hand does something when you include it:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.class_eval do
    extend  ActiveModel::Naming
    extend  ActiveModel::Translation
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
  end
end
```

When you include `ActiveModel::Model`, the `included` method is called, which includes the `ActiveModel::Naming`, `ActiveModel::Validations`, etc. Those do mix methods into your class. Also see the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/model.rb) for `ActiveModel::Model`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. One follow up question: When would it actually be relevant only to include ActiveModel then?

Comment: I can't think of any scenario, as its main purpose is just to set up some references for loading.